# INSERT INTO from tableA to tableB with count()

Tags: sql, sybase

Inserting rows from one table to another table, I try to use a count(*) to ensure that the line_no column in table OBJ_LINES is set to 1,2,3,4.. and so on for every line added.

```
INSERT INTO OBJ_LINES(
id,
line_no)
SELECT (1,
(select count(*)+1 FROM OBJ_LINES WHERE id = 1)
FROM TEMPLATE_LINES tmp
WHERE tmp.id = 37;
```

(syntax Sybase Database)
If the TEMPLATE_LINES table holds more than one row, I get a duplicate error as the count() seems to be evaluted only once, and not for every row found in the TEMPLATE_LINES table.

How may I write the sql to set 'dynamic' line_no depending on the current number of rows for a given id?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: If this is SQL Server, use an `IDENTITY` column in the target table or use `ROW_NUMBER()` if you have a high enough version of SQL Server. Always add a tag for the database version otherwise we are guessing.

Comment: You're getting an error because SQL is (primarily) involved with set-based operations. The entire `INSERT` statement is processed "as if" all of the rows are being operated on in parallel. So, whilst it's performing the `SELECT` part of the query, **no** new rows exist in the destination table. So all of the subquery evaluations that count the number of rows in the target table count the *same* number of rows. And then it attempts to insert *all* of those rows.

Comment: Sybase was a company, not a database - which Sybase database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO OBJ_LINES(
id,
line_no)
SELECT (1,
number(*)
FROM TEMPLATE_LINES tmp
WHERE tmp.id = 37;
```